# Flash CS4 and SWC file library path's

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, swc

I have a SWC file with a skinned version of the ActionScript 3 UI components. I want to use this SWC file on 'some' of my projects so instead of dropping the file in the `Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\Components` path, which makes it available to every Flash project, I add the path to my SWC file in the `Publish Settings > Flash > Settings > Library Path` dialog. However, what ever I try the components do not show up in my Components panel.

How do get my skinned components to show up in the Components panel without making it a global library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your folder in Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\Components that will be available from the Components Panel, which means for all documents.

I'm not sure what you mean by "without making it a global library"

If you want those components to be accessed from the IDE, but not grouped with the other Components, just don't put in the components. How about using the Common Libraries ?

Put your SWCs in an fla file saved in this path: Adobe Flash CS4\en\Configuration\Libraries 
You would then access that library from Window > Libraries > YourCustomComponents